# Clone Mediaotor Not working in WSO2 ESB 4.8.1

Tags: soap, wso2, wso2-esb

I have defined a **"Validate"** Mediator fault sequence. I want that if my validation is failed. Message should be sent back to the client as well as to a queue based on JMS.

**Problem:**

Clone mediator is not working. I am using clone mediator to send message to the queue and then "Respond" mediator to send message back to the client.

**Note:**
If I remove the clone mediator, the message is perfectly send back to the client. But with clone mediator it is not working.

**Validate Mediator Code:**

```
 <validate>
         <schema xmlns:ns2="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" key="gov:/xsd/testschema.xsd"></schema>
         <on-fail>
            <makefault version="soap11">
               <detail xmlns:ns2="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" expression="get-property('ERROR_DETAIL')"></detail>
            </makefault>
            <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
               <format>
                  <ErrorMessage xmlns="">
                     <ErrorCode>007</ErrorCode>
                     <ErrorMessage>Not Correct Request</ErrorMessage>
                  </ErrorMessage>
               </format>
            </payloadFactory>
            <clone continueParent="true" sequential="false">
               <target>
                  <endpoint>
                     <address uri="jms:/ErrorQueue?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&amp;java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&amp;java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616&amp;transport.jms.DestinationType=queue"></address>
                  </endpoint>
               </target>
            </clone>
            <respond></respond>
         </on-fail>
      </validate>
```

**Exception:**

Uncaught exception {org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool}
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPFault
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPBodyImpl.getFault(SOAPBodyImpl.java:120)
    at org.apache.synapse.util.MessageHelper.cloneSOAPEnvelope(MessageHelper.java:383)
    at org.apache.synapse.util.MessageHelper.cloneAxis2MessageContext(MessageHelper.java:233)
    at org.apache.synapse.util.MessageHelper.cloneMessageContext(MessageHelper.java:86)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.eip.splitter.CloneMediator.getClonedMessageContext(CloneMediator.java:159)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.eip.splitter.CloneMediator.mediate(CloneMediator.java:99)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.ValidateMediator.mediate(ValidateMediator.java:212)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.TemplateMediator.mediate(TemplateMediator.java:77)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.InvokeMediator.mediate(InvokeMediator.java:129)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.InvokeMediator.mediate(InvokeMediator.java:78)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:196)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:166)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:411)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:183)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)

**Note:**
I also didn't define anything in "SOAP Action" field in "Clone" mediator.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug in ESB 4.8.1. Please check this [1]

1.https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-3087

Try this with call mediator and enrich mediator. I have not tested this.

```
<validate>
         <schema xmlns:ns2="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" key="gov:/xsd/testschema.xsd"></schema>
         <on-fail>
            <makefault version="soap11">
               <detail xmlns:ns2="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" expression="get-property('ERROR_DETAIL')"></detail>
            </makefault>
            <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
               <format>
                  <ErrorMessage xmlns="">
                     <ErrorCode>007</ErrorCode>
                     <ErrorMessage>Not Correct Request</ErrorMessage>
                  </ErrorMessage>
               </format>
            </payloadFactory>

        **<property name="BODY_ELEMENTS" expression="$body">**
            **<call>**

                  <endpoint>
                     <address uri="jms:/ErrorQueue?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&amp;java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&amp;java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616&amp;transport.jms.DestinationType=queue"></address>
                  </endpoint>

            **</call>**
    **<enrich>
            <source xpath="$ctx:BODY_ELEMENTS/> 
            <target type="body"/>
    </enrich>**   
            <respond></respond>
         </on-fail>
      </validate>
```

Comment: Is there any other way around it. Or any other approach to achieve this goal.

Comment: check i have updated the answer, actually when there is soapfault in the message,mediators behave abnormally , as i know for clone and xslt mediator same bug exists. not sure about enrich .check if that works then fine

Comment: what should be the enrich "target" action.  It is either "replace","child" or "siblings".

Comment: I have tried your approach. Message is successfully send to the queue. But no response send back to the client.

Comment: add this property <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2" action="remove"></property> before <respond> tag

enrich action is 'replace'

Comment: Same result. Message is successfully sent to queue but not back to the client. What happening is that call mediator after sending message to the queue is waiting for response. There will be no response so it keeps waiting and after sometimes it gives timeout error. So is there anything to make call mediator a asynchronous call.